# Charts for iOS: limit displayed entries number to 4 in LineChartView

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm using LineChartView to draw line charts in our application. The newest requirement is that the chart displays only 4 records at once, so the X-zoom must be limited to 4 entries. Is this achievable using this library without doing any hacky stuff? I'd rather avoid calculating zoom manually.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to see only 4 values at a time. 
This can be accomplished by using:

```
chartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 4.0, maxXRange: 4.0)
```

The chart will be scrollable to the sides.
The scroll can be turned off, but then only the 4 first values will be viewable:

```
chartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the graph auto scroll along +X-axis:

let any_value_in_double = 100.00

chartView.moveViewToX(any_value_in_double)

This graph will starts moving toward the right after 4.0 values as mentioned in the above Ranges.